# Set an OnClickListener for an SVG element

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Say I have an SVG element, as follows.  How do I add an onClickListener?

```
solved, see below.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone's interested in how it's done...

```
try {
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/svg/sphere1.svg");

            _image = (SVGImage)SVGImage.createImage(inputStream, null);   

            _animator = SVGAnimator.createAnimator(_image, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");

            _document = _image.getDocument(); 

            _svg123 = (SVGElement)_document.getElementById("123");


        }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        Field _svgField = (Field)_animator.getTargetComponent();        

        _svgField.setBackground(blackBackground);

        add(_svgField);

        _svg123.addEventListener("click", this, false);
        _svg123.addEventListener("DOMFocusIn", this, false);
        _svg123.addEventListener("DOMFocusOut", this, false);


    }

    public void handleEvent(Event evt) {

        if( _svg123 == evt.getCurrentTarget() && evt.getType() == "click" ){ Dialog.alert("You clicked 123"); }

        if( _svg123 == evt.getCurrentTarget() && evt.getType() == "DOMFocusIn" ) { ((SVGElement) _document.getElementById("outStroke123")).setTrait("fill", "#FF0000");     }
        if( _svg123 == evt.getCurrentTarget() && evt.getType() == "DOMFocusOut" ) { ((SVGElement) _document.getElementById("outStroke123")).setTrait("fill", "#2F4F75");    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess you're meaning a `FieldChangeListener` rather than an `OnClickListener` (wrong platform ;). `SVGImage` isn't part of the RIM-developed objects, so unfortunately you won't be able to. Anything that is going to be able to have a `FieldChangeListner` has to be a subclass of the `net.rim.device.api.ui.Field` class.

Comment: Hmm... ok, then is there a way to detect a click on a SVG element?

Comment: You may take a look at http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/SVG-BitmapField/td-p/677495 where they did some conversion and used a `BitmapField`, which can have a `FieldChangeListener`